# Unable to parse bulk JSON POST request to Kinvey back-end

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, kinvey

When I try to parse this JSON:

```
[
{"name":"name1","id":12},
{"name":"name2","id":11},
{"name":"name3","id":111},
{"name":"name4","id":1115}
]
```

in a POST request to Kinvey's BAAS, I get the error:

```
{
  "error": "Unable to parse the JSON in the request"
}
```

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/xoxty9pez/full/) is a screenshot of my back-end (Kinvey).

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/9qtnlzoq3/full/) is a screenshot of my request (Postman).

When I send the single entity `{"name":"name1","id":12}` it doesn't throw an error and places it in the back-end as it should. Picture here: [Kinvey worked](http://postimg.org/image/cnh55nbhn/full/)

Comment: This is a valid json verified from http://jsonutils.com/. Are you deserializing in the backend.

Comment: Is this JSON copied & pasted? Could be the break lines. Did you try the same data as a single line?

Comment: what is "deserializing in the backend"? :)

Comment: how about using `{"mydata":[
{"name":"name1","id":12},
{"name":"name2","id":11},
{"name":"name3","id":111},
{"name":"name4","id":1115}
]}`

Comment: ye is di this `{"name":[{"name":"name1","id":12},{"name":"name2","id":11},{"name":"name3","id"‌​:111},{"name":"name4","id":1115}]}` , but now the result is postimg.org/image/kr54wzxm3/full but how do i make them in individual rows

Comment: you cannot upload/post multiple entities at the same time. see also my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security measure, some frameworks won't parse top-level arrays as JSON. Doing so enabled exploits in some older browsers.

The exploit goes something like this:

1. Write some Javascript that replaces `Array` with a function that stores its contents to some other variable.
2. In your malicious site, include a request to some privileged (JSON Array) resource on another server using a `<script>` tag.
3. Trick a user with privileges on that server into visiting your site.

The requested resource will be pulled from the benign server, loaded in the user's browser as a script, and evaluated— but the array gets handled by your malicious substitute function, which you can use however you like. A form of [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

### Update

Regarding the question, "how do I upload multiple entities to a Kinvey collection?", the answer is in the [Kinvey documentation](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/datastore#create):

> "For bulk upload, see the CSV/JSON import feature on the Kinvey console (navigate to the collection, click Settings, then click Import Data)."

Comment: so what can i  do to parse this, i don't want to send an individual ajax for every collumn in my collection

Comment: Wrap the whole thing up in an object! The JSON could be, `{ "myArray" : [ . . .] }`

Comment: ye is di this `{"name":[{"name":"name1","id":12},{"name":"name2","id":11},{"name":"name3","id":111},{"name":"name4","id":1115}]}` , but now the result is http://postimg.org/image/kr54wzxm3/full/   but how do i make them in individual rows

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: i mean 1st roll should be name= name1, id = id12, second row should be name = name2, id = id11 here is a picture [http://postimg.org/image/xm8ktjzzf/full/)

Comment: According to [this thread](https://support.kinvey.com/support/discussions/topics/5000040991) from **2 years ago**, posting multiple entities to an endpoint is not possible. Your question may be better suited the kinvey forums, since you are asking specifically about their API infrastructure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113310/discussion-between---and-this-vidor).

Comment: ah, ok thank you, i thought the problem was in me and spend 2 hours on on it

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/datastore#create), there is a way! "For bulk upload, see the CSV/JSON import feature on the Kinvey console (navigate to the collection, click Settings, then click Import Data)."

Answer (score 1):

You can only POST one entity at a time with the POST function in Kinvey. So this is not a JSON parsing error.

Also, you should look into calling Kinvey through the official Kinvey SDK for the mobile platform you're developing for, rather than using the REST API. That way, you can take advantage of many other features such as caching, offline sync, implicit authentication, etc.

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but this is kinda of homework thing, to learn how to use Rest API BAAS